# Word for a hollowed-out book?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the word or term for a hollowed-out book used to contain objects.  I've heard the terms *book safe* and the colorful term *smuggler's Bible*, but an acquaintance swears there's a single word for this that he does not remember.

Any ideas?  Any other terms?  Pic for reference.

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia calls these "[Hollow-book safes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concealing_objects_in_a_book#Hollow_Book_Safes)" and you can buy them under that name on e.g. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hollow+book+safe&sprefix=hollow+book+s%2Caps%2C130).

Comment: _Stashbook_, maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest single-word answer for you I can find is "solander."

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solander) has

> A protective box made in the form of a book, for holding such items as botanical specimens, maps, papers, etc.
>
> late 18th century: named after Daniel C. Solander (1736–82), Swedish botanist.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! This seems a good word, so I added in some corroboration for you. Please do that for your future answers. (Hopefully the downvote your original answer gained will be reversed.)

Comment: This is not it. This is a box that looks like a book: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Solander_Box.jpg/220px-Solander_Box.jpg

Comment: This was the word my acquaintance was looking for.  Not exactly the same thing as a book safe, but I think it's the closest thing that's one word.

Comment: @j.i.h.: Why do you put a misleading picture if you were not sure what it is then?

Answer (score 2):

"Hollow book safe" and the like seem to be the only names I can find for such an object. Perhaps your friend was thinking of a *steganograph*, a message hidden inside a book through the use of invisible ink, a cipher, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Repository. Not necessarily referring to a book per say, but a book safe is a repository of sorts.

Word Reference gives:

> [repository](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/repository) n (storage place)
>
> *The spare bedroom is a repository for all sorts of things we no longer use, but don't want to throw out.*

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary definition of your suggested word.

Comment: The word is unlikely to bring to mind a book-shaped object.